# rails check_box value using translation I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, rails-i18n

just wondering how I should do internationalization in rails when using a checkbox in a normal (very simple) form;
This is what I tried:

`view/form` file:

```
<%= f.check_box :do_you_agree, {}, t('submissions.yes'), t('submissions.no') %>
<%= f.check_box :do_you_agree, {}, I18n.t('submissions.yes'), I18n.t('submissions.no') %>
<%= f.check_box :do_you_agree, {}, "#{t('submissions.yes')}", "#{t('submissions.no')}" %>
```

...and all them return:
`translation_missing` in HTML.

When I use :

```
<%= f.check_box :do_you_agree, {}, 'NO', 'YES' %>
```

...everything is ok!

The YML file is ok. Many thanks.

Comment: does it work when you print out the  `I18n.t('submissions.yes')` in the html page elsewhere

Comment: @ant, yes is does work. I guess the problem is within the check_box option/syntax

Answer (score 1):

In your `config/application.rb` you must have the line `config.i18n.default_locale = :es` (:es for spanish, as an example)

And the yml must be like this:

```
es:
  submissions:
    'yes': Si
    'no': No
```

**Edit**: Make the yes/no keys explicit strings. And it will works.

Why? Because Rails does yaml conversion with [psych](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/Gemfile#L111) gem. And psych return [true](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/master/test/psych/test_boolean.rb#L8) and [false](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/master/test/psych/test_boolean.rb#L14) with all those values (see the links).

Then, if you define a locales this way:

```
es:
  submissions:
    yes: Si
    no: No
```

at the rails console you get:

```
irb> I18n.t('submissions')
=> {true=>"Si",false=>"No"}
irb> I18n.t('submissions')[true]
=> "Si"
irb> I18n.t('submissions.true')
=> "translation missing: es.submissions.true"
```

Comment: that's right, even though you are not answering the question.

Comment: @embasbm : I answer why you must use strings with keys yes/no, on/off and true/false on locales files.